# New ContentItem from code, when is it saved?

Tags: orchardcms

I can't get my head around this.

If I have a `ContentType` called `Contacts`. The `ContentType` has two fields attached to it.

`FirstName (textfield)` and `LastName (textfield)`.

If I want to create a new `contentitem` of this type then I can write code like this.

```
dynamic contact = _services.ContentManager.New("Contacts");
contact.Contacts.FirstName.Value = "John";
contact.Contacts.LastName.Value = "Doe";
_services.ContentManager.Create(contact, VersionOptions.Published);
```

This does not work. The `Contentitem` gets created but the fields are empty.

However, if I write it like this it works. Why is that? Must I set the fields values after `ContentManager.Create` is called?

```
dynamic contact = _services.ContentManager.New("Contacts");
_services.ContentManager.Create(contact, VersionOptions.Published);
contact.Contacts.FirstName.Value = "John";
contact.Contacts.LastName.Value = "Doe";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you observed is indeed the intended behaviour and is by design. I've come across this before too and also [created an issue](http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18412) about it. As you can see there it was closed by Sebastien, the lead developer stating that this is by design but unfortunately not explaining why.

FYI the standard workflow for managing content items is the following:

1. Instantiate item.
2. Create it.
3. Update its values.
4. If the update happened through the model binder then check if the ModelState is valid. If not, cancel the transaction and return.
5. If everything's OK and the content type is set to be draftable, publish the item.

You can see an explained example of this in the [Orchard Training Demo module](https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d289c6fd344d#Controllers/ContentsAdminController.cs) (ContentsAdminController.PersonListDashboardPost()).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Piedone. I suspected that was the case. It makes more sense to:

- Instansiate
- Assign properties
- Create Item

Comment: Yes, from a consuming perspective this indeed makes more sense.

Comment: It would be great if you'd mark my answer as answer if it was helpful.